# Android AppWidget Lifecycle

Tags: android

I am finding during a reboot that the AppWidget onUpdate method is being called twice - on very clean basic code - with a correct manifest. My code is not an issue, this problem is definitely system related (hence I'm not posting any code).

Has this been resolved post 2.3.7 (my current development platform)?

How does one eliminate this programmatically? As my onUpdate often calls a service (to eliminate ANR on slow stuff) I am forced to resolve the issue with a pseudo-semaphore approach. Not ideal.

Thanks.